# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{1-\cos(x^2)}{\sum_{n=4}^\infty {n^5x^n} }$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I am trying to calculate the following limit:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{1}{1-\cos(x^2)}{\sum_{n=4}^\infty {n^5 x^n} }$$

In general, I don't really know how to deal with Limits of infinite summation, so I tried to turn the series into a function, but I couldn't find the function.

Any help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using L'Hôpital's Rule (twice) we get that 
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^4}{1-\cos (x^2)}=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{y^2}{1-\cos y}=2.
$$
Then
$$
\sum_{n=4}^\infty n^5x^n=x^4\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+4)^5 x^n=x^4 f(x),
$$
and the power series $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+4)^5 x^n$ has radius of convergence $r=1$ (using ratio test) and $f(0)=4^5=1024$.
Thus
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{1-\cos (x^2)}\sum_{n=4}^\infty n^5x^n=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^4}{1-\cos x}\cdot  f(x)=2 \cdot f(0)=2048.
$$

Comment: This would be true if the question didn't feature $1-\cos x^2$ in the denominator, not $\cos x$.

Comment: @5xum: Yes - It is correct now.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to expand $\cos x^2$ into a Taylor series, then cancel out $x^4$ in the fraction.
See:

$$\cos x = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} - \dots$$

Therefore $$1-\cos(x^2) = \frac{x^4}{2!} - \frac{x^8}{4!} + \frac{x^{12}}{6!}-\cdots=\\=x^4\left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{x^4 }{4!}+\frac{x^{12}}{6!} - \cdots\right)$$

As for the numerator, it equals $$4^5x^4 + 5^5 x^5 + 6^5 x^6\cdots=\\=x^4\left(4^5 + 5^5x + 6^5x^2+\dots\right).$$

Writing the fraction allows you to cancel out $x^4$, sending $x$ to $0$ tell you that all the factors stil containing $x$ will equal zero, leaving you with the solution.

Comment: because it is a infinite summation, you can't say that " all the factors stil containing x will equal zero, leaving you with the solution.".

Comment: Well, there's some work with proving the convergence radius, but if the reader knows what a Taylor series is, the path to the solution is clear from my answer.

Comment: +1 - while I appreciate the value of teaching students L'Hôpital's Rule, this is the way I pretty much always do it 'in practice', and the way everyone else I know does it too.

Answer (score 1):

As $\displaystyle\cos2y=1-2\sin^2y,1-\cos(x^2)=2\sin^2\dfrac{x^2}2$ which $O(x^4)$

As  for $|x|<1,$ and  setting $\displaystyle\frac1x=y$
$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} n^5x^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^5}{y^n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{5n^4}{y^n\ln y}$ (using L'Hospitals)

$\displaystyle\implies\lim_{n\to\infty} n^5x^n=\cdots=0$

So, each term $ n^5 x^n$ will vanish for $n\ge5$

Comment: Could you please explain your solution? Becuase, we already know that for |x|<1, $n^5x^n$ converges to 0, and how does it help us find the desired limit?

Comment: @Sefi,  so, we have  $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{4^5x^4}{2\sin^2\frac{x^2}2}+0=4^5\lim_{y\to0}\frac{(2y)^4}{2\sin^2(2y^2)}$$  $$=\frac{4^52^5}{2\cdot2^2}\left(\lim_{y\to0}\frac{2y^2}{\sin2y^2}\right)^2$$